# WebRequest keeps encoding my data

Tags: c#, .net, webrequest

I am using the following code. I have a problem in which 'parameters' is a string I have space characters inside, and no matter if I use HttpUtility.UrlDecode(parameters) before converting it to bytes, in Wireshark I see the postdata does bla+bla+bla and not bla bla bla.

What is causing this? the encoding?

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);

// Set the Method property of the request to POST.
request.Method = "POST";

// Create POST data and convert it to a byte array.
string postData = parameters;
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


// Set the ContentType property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// Set the ContentLength property of the WebRequest.
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

// Get the request stream.
Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

// Write the data to the request stream.
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

// Close the Stream object.
dataStream.Close();

// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

// Display the content.
string res = responseFromServer;

// Clean up the streams.
reader.Close();
dataStream.Close();
response.Close();

return res;
```

Comment: I've just run the code and debugged using Fiddler and it isn't encoding the spaces, could this be wireshark somehow?

Comment: No, because I have a request coming in this app, and I am forwarding it to another server (that is, my app is PROXY). the incoming request comes with spaces and the POST i am doing here is doing +

Comment: If you don't want your data to be urlencoded, why are you using x-www-form-urlencoded?  That tells anything the gets the data (or intercepts the data) that the data is url-encoded...

Comment: Try setting ContentType to "text/plain".  Better yet, if your app is a proxy, re-use the original content-type...

Comment: Hi, the incoming is x-www-form-urlencoded, thats why I am forwarding it the same